# Cannot convert a row to a DataTable in C#

Tags: c#, database, datatable, datarow

I'm trying to convert a `DataRow` to a `DataTable`, but I'm getting errors. I searched and tried all possible solutions, but none worked!

I have a method which accepts a `DataTable` as its parameter (this `DataTable` has one row exactly). That method will return some information.

At first, I tried to convert the `DataRow` to a `DataTable` using `ImportRow(newtable.ImportRow(row))`, but `newtable` is empty afterward. Then, I tried `dt.clone()`, but this fills the `newtable` with just everything, which is not what I was after! Actually the exact thing I was after.

```
private static void BatchFrontSidePrinting(Student St, frmBaseCard frm)
{
    DBINFOPACK UserInfo;
    DBCARDINFO CardInfo;
    DataTable newtable = new DataTable("newtable");

    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        try
        {

            // here, I'm trying to send one DataRow as a DataTable to the GetInfo() method,
            // and for the next iteratio , after getting the info I'm removing the row which was just added,
            // so that for the next iteration, newdatatable is empty.  All of the proceeding actions fail !:( 

            newtable.ImportRow(row); // doesn't work! 

            UserInfo = GetInfo(newtable);

            newtable.Rows.Remove(row); // doesn't work! 

            St = UserInfo.STUDENT;

            ((frmFrontSideCard)frm).Replica = UserInfo.CARDINFO.Replica;

            if (UserInfo.CARDINFO.Replica)
            {
                Loger.Items.Add("Replication !");
            }

            // print
            ((frmFrontSideCard)frm).Print = St;

            // update
            CardInfo = UserInfo.CARDINFO;
            CardInfo.SID = UserInfo.STUDENT.ID;
            CardInfo.BIMAGE = UserInfo.BIMAGE;
            SetInfo(CardInfo);
        }
        catch (Exception exep)
        {
            Loger.Items.Add(String.Format("Inside [BatchFrontSidePrinting()] : Student {0} {1}:", St.ID, exep.Message));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    try
    {
        DataTable newtable = new DataTable();
        newtable = dt.Clone(); // Use Clone method to copy the table structure (Schema).
        newtable.ImportRow(row); // Use the ImportRow method to copy from dt table to its clone.
        UserInfo = GetInfo(newtable);

    catch (Exception exep)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou , but im planning on making a DataTable which only contains one row , this method will make my dataTable contain what i have in the main dataTable ( with everysingle rows! )which is not applicable for the GetInfo() Methods .

Comment: Clone function only the schema will be copied.

Answer (score 1):

```
var someRow = newTable.NewRow();
someRow[0] = row[0]; // etc
newTable.Rows.Add(someRow);
```

Comment: Thank you sir. 
but this cpde generates an error : saying , Cannot find column 0. 
changing it to 
someRow = row 
generates another error saying : This row already belongs to another table.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using `newtable` as a temporary container to send each row in `dt` to the `GetInfo` method.  If so, why not change the `GetInfo` method to take a `DataRow` rather than a `DataTable` that contains a single `DataRow`?  Then you can get rid of `newtable` and not bother with creating and copying `DataRow`s in the first place.

```
private static void BatchFrontSidePrinting(Student St, frmBaseCard frm) 
{ 
    DBINFOPACK UserInfo ; 
    DBCARDINFO CardInfo; 

    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows) 
    { 
        try 
        {       
            // just pass the row
            UserInfo = GetInfo(row); 

            // rest of the code as before
            St = UserInfo.STUDENT; 
            ((frmFrontSideCard)frm).Replica = UserInfo.CARDINFO.Replica; 
            if (UserInfo.CARDINFO.Replica) 
            { 
                Loger.Items.Add("Replication !"); 
            } 
            //print 
            ((frmFrontSideCard)frm).Print = St; 
            //update 
            CardInfo = UserInfo.CARDINFO; 
            CardInfo.SID = UserInfo.STUDENT.ID; 
            CardInfo.BIMAGE = UserInfo.BIMAGE; 
            SetInfo(CardInfo); 
        } 
        catch (Exception exep) 
        { 
            Loger.Items.Add(String.Format("Inside [BatchFrontSidePrinting()] : Student {0} {1}:", St.ID, exep.Message)); 
        }
```

Comment: Thankyou , the reason behind this , is that there are couple of other methods which work with DataTable and this solution would keep the changes to the minimum .
i made another method which accepts a DataRow , and its fine for now till i get the time to fix other methods :) 
Thank you again